# How to install docker in docker container?

Tags: docker, debian, dockerfile

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang
# RUN cat /etc/*release
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl gnupg2 software-properties-common
RUN curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | apt-key add -
RUN add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian $(lsb_release -cs) stable"

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install docker-ce
RUN docker run hello-world
```

The golang Dockerfile is official, it bases on the

```
Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)
```

So I wrote down this Dockerfile by checking the install steps from [Docker Install Tutor(Debian)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/debian/)

But the output is

```
Step 8/8 : RUN docker run hello-world
 ---> Running in b183b8cc5d10
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at 
unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

#### How to solve this problem? I want to establish docker containers in the host docker container.

Answer (score 19):

I had a similar problem trying to install Docker inside a Bamboo Server image. To solve this:

1. first remove the line: **RUN docker run hello-world** from your `Dockerfile`
2. The simplest way is to just expose the Docker socket, by bind-mounting it with the `-v` flag or mounting a volume using `Docker Compose`:

`docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ...`

Comment: This is preferable to running Docker-in-Docker in many cases, for the reasons referenced in jonashackt's link: https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/

Comment: This does not work because it requires you to already have built the container (e.g. `docker run`). If the Dockerfile recipe includes steps that invoke Docker (`docker build ...`), then this will not help.

Comment: Bind mounts are not a recommended way to do this since this creates a dependence on the host system

Comment: None of this works in a practical situation, like custom images for CI/CD pipelines. It's fine that you can do it locally on your personal computer but can you do it in cloudbuild or whatever the AWS equivalent is?

Answer (score 11):

In your `.dockerfile` add this line to install Docker:

```sh
RUN curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com | sh
```

After build is done, when running your container, add a volume mapping to the host Docker socket with the `-v` switch , e.g.:

```sh
docker run --rm -it -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock my-container
```

Then, from within the container shell, check the connection by running:

```
# docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                       NAMES
8bf420851572   my-image               "bash"                   8 minutes ago   Up 8 minutes                               my-container
```

Comment: `Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock`.

Comment: `chmod 777 /var/run/docker.sock` worked...

Comment: dont you have to add the user your running in the container as to the docker group within the container?

Comment: How is this flag usable in cloudbuild or a kubernetes situation? How would you -v if you're not doing a docker run but actually using the container. We are trying to do a CI/CD situation and we need docker in a custom container.

Comment: Doing this leaves a lot of files under `/var/lib/apt/lists`… that's not a great practice, is it?

Comment: With man pages and locale files, that's 147M worth of files in my case 

Answer (score 6):

Use [Docker-in-Docker](https://github.com/jpetazzo/dind) for this task. They have already solved many of the problems for you.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use the official Docker-in-Docker images from https://hub.docker.com/_/docker/ with the `:dind` tag (which is the successor of the project [Hendrikvh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4444761/hendrikvh) already mentioned).

You definitely need to use the `--priviledged` flag also:

```
docker run --privileged --name yourDockerContainerNameHere -d docker:dind
```

With that your Docker-in-Docker experiments should work - but be aware of the many stumbleblocks that could be in your way: https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/

Answer (score 0):

```
   //create container in privileged mode
    sudo docker container run -it --name uob_20.04 --privileged=true <dockerhub-image> /bin/bash
   //give access
    sudo chmod ugo+rw /var/run/docker.sock
    sudo nohup dockerd > /dev/null 2>&1 &
    //check docker installation
    docker images
```

Answer (score -1):

Just do this:

```
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y jq
RUN apt-get install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl software-properties-common
RUN curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | apt-key add -
RUN add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal stable"
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y docker-ce
```

Comment: It would be better not to use exclamation mark as pointed [here](https://www.themuse.com/advice/a-friendly-persons-guide-to-using-exclamation-marks-correctly-and-incorrectly#:~:text=But%20Lose%20it%20When%20You%E2%80%99re%20Being%20Stern) and you should write the command in verbatim mode for clearer reading.

Answer (score -4):

Try with starting docker service before of executing any docker command.
Add this line

```
RUN bash service docker start
```

to your Dockerfile above of this line:

```
RUN docker run hello-world
```

Comment: That doesn´t work for me - it just spits out `service docker not recognized`.

Comment: RUN sudo /etc/init.d/docker start ,run this command it will work