# How do I run a docker command inside of a docker container?

Tags: docker

I know that this question has been asked before but I guess that I am a dunce or something because none of the answers have been able to help me.

Here is my situation ... I am working on a testing framework where I am abstracting the loin's share of the work and only pass a minimal amount of requirements onto the actual tests configurations.  To do this I have containerized my framework and am using repositories for the actual test configurations.  You pass my framework a repo and it clones the repo, executes a setup script from within that repo, and then looks for a special output file containing some test instructions.

The problem is that some of the test configurations setup scripts want to use "docker run" so I need to have docker available in my container.  I've tried using the "-v /var/run/docker.socks:/var/run/docker.socks" as so many have said should help, but that does not solve the problem that the docker executable does not exist anywhere in the container's PATH.

What am I missing?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Search for [tag:dind] ([Docker in Docker](https://www.google.com/search?q=dind)).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44451859/how-to-install-docker-in-docker-container